# Python: Average values in a CSV file based on value of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am a noob and I have a large CSV file with data structured like this (with a lot more columns):

```
State  daydiff
CT     5.5
CT     6.5
CT     6.25
NY     3.2
NY     3.225
PA     7.522
PA     4.25
```

I want to output a new CSV where the `daydiff` is averaged for each `State` like this:

```
State  daydiff
CT     6.083
NY     3.2125
PA     5.886
```

I have tried numerous ways and the cleanest seemed to leverage pandas `groupby` but when i run the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:...input.csv')
df.groupby('State')['daydiff'].mean()

df.to_csv('C:...AverageOutput.csv')
```

I get a file that is identical to the original file but with a counter added in the first column with no header:

```
,State,daydiff
0,CT,5.5
1,CT,6.5
2,CT,6.25
3,NY,3.2
4,NY,3.225
5,PA,7.522
6,PA,4.25
```

I was also hoping to control the new average in `datediff` to a decimal going out only to the hundredths. Thanks

Comment: Use `df.to_csv('C:...AverageOutput.csv', index=False)`
`

Comment: @Zero Thanks. That solved the extra column but now the output is identical to the input with no averaging happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" with the counter is because the default behaviour for `to_csv`is to write the index. You should do `df.to_csv('C:...AverageOutput.csv', index=False)`.

You can control the output format of daydiff by converting it to string. `df.daydiff = df.daydiff.apply(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x))`

Your complete code should be:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:...input.csv')
df2 = df.groupby('State')['daydiff'].mean().apply(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x))
df2.to_csv('C:...AverageOutput.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved the extra column but now the output is identical to the input with no averaging happening.

Comment: Take care of the variable your outputting `to_csv`. You you output `df.to_csv` you are writing the original data to the new file. You have to make sure you're using `df2.to_csv`. I've updated my answer since the `groupby` will output a `Series`, not a `DataFrame`. Since it's a `Series` you *need* the index.

Comment: That worked great thanks, but it did not carry over the headers as I expected.